# Netlogo: How to subset with row and column indexes

Tags: netlogo

Could someone help me out with the code on reading in data in `Netlogo`? I am trying to choose one element in multiple lists to assign it to the turtle as a variable (I have the data in a rectangular table read from a csv file).

In my current code, it reads as I want but the problem is it is reading only elements of one last row instead of iteratively reading elements (across columns) of all rows. What I need is to read one element of each row at a time.

[here are some rows of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hXJOA.png)

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
let residents-file "mock-data.csv"
  let residents-list []
  set residents-list csv:from-file residents-file
  
  
  foreach residents-list [ ?1 ->
    let hh-col ?1row
    let residents-to-create 1 
    
    create-residents residents-to-create [ setxy random-xcor random-ycor ]    
    ask residents [ 
      set shape "person"
      set color 9
      set ID item 0 hh-col
      set occupancy item 1 hh-col]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you are using `create-residents` to create *n* residents, but then asking **all** residents to do something. In other words, no matter which row is currently being processed, all of the existing residents (whether created in this iteration or created in previous iterations) are being asked to pull the values from the row that is being processed on the current iteration.

The easiest way to fix this is probably just to have each resident pull the values *as* it's being created.

With this toy version of your dataset:

```
id  occupancy
1   owner
2   renter
3   owner
4   renter
5   owner
```

Here is a simplified example:

```
breed [ residents resident ]
residents-own [ id occupancy ]

extensions [csv]

to setup
  ca
  let residents-file "mock-data.csv"
  let residents-list but-first csv:from-file residents-file
  
  foreach residents-list [ cur-row ->
    create-residents 1 [
      set id item 0 cur-row
      set occupancy item 1 cur-row
    ]
  ]
  
  ask residents [
    print ( word "My who is " who ", my id is " id ", and my occupancy is " occupancy )
  ]
    
  reset-ticks
end
```

Output should look something like:

[image]

Comment: Hi Luke, thanks a lot, yes true, it works now!